# Strikeout formula inside eqnarray?

Tags: math-mode, strikeout

I want to strikeout a part of my paper. In particular, this one:

```
When bla bla $s$ bla bla $v$, bla bla $\boldsymbol{x}_{v}$, bla bla, the equation is:
\begin{eqnarray}
\displaystyle p_{v,s} & = & \displaystyle v+s = \nonumber\\
& = & \displaystyle  v^{2} - s^{3}. \label{eqn:pvs}
\end{eqnarray}
```

I've tried with `\cancel` but this only works with the first part of the text:

```
\cancel{When bla bla $s$ bla bla $v$, bla bla $\boldsymbol{x}_{v}$, bla bla, the equation is:}
```

and I get error when I use it on `eqnarray`. I've also tried `\sout` but the result was the same.

**Additions**

This is what I get when I use `\sout` on the text part. I would like that also the equation is stricken out!

[image]

Comment: As a starting point, see [`eqnarray` vs `align`](http://goo.gl/3R7Ln) (in favour of using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `align` environment(s)). Then, you're probably including the alignments `&` inside the `\cancel`, which cannot be done. Can you include a visual of what you're after exactly in the form of an uploaded image?

Comment: The `\displaystyle` directives to the right of the alignment points are unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that \displaystyle affects \cancel or \sout?

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to *directly* span a `\cancel` or `\sout` across the alignment points `&` since each "cell" forms a group. That is, you want to start inside one group and span across to another group. One way around this might be to use [`tikzmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) to remember left/right nodes inside a display, or overlay the <s>strikeout</s> after the fact. I've chosen to do the latter here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,ulem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,ulem}
\begin{document}
\sout{When bla bla~$s$ bla bla~$v$, bla bla~$\boldsymbol{x}_v$, bla bla, the equation is:}
\begin{align}
  p_{v,s} &= v + s\llap{\sout{\phantom{$p_{v,s} = v + s$}}} \nonumber \\
          &= v^2 - s^3.\llap{\sout{\phantom{$= v^2 - s^3.$}}} \label{eqn:pvs}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to set the equation as-is and then (at the end of each row/line) insert a zero-width `l`eft over`lap` where you `\sout` (or `\cancel`) the same equation. Using `\phantom` gives you the correct spacing without re-setting the content.

If you use the same approach using `eqnarray`, you'll obtain an incorrect layout, since `eqnarray` doesn't provide the correct spacing around the aligned item.